# how to prevent scp/ssh from trying to read standard input

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, scp

I am passing a file from one server to another using authorized keys.
However, in the event keys are no longer valid, the script is being asked for the password on and on.

I have tried

```
scp ${user}@$host}:/tmp ./file1 </dev/null
```

but I still get the prompt.
The only time when this works is if I run it off schedule like this:

```
echo "scp ${user}@$host}:/tmp ./file1" | at now
```

In this case it will correctly error out if keys are no longer valid.

But how can I create a blank input stream, that will not be prompting the user if the script is run interactively?

@David:

```
echo "" | scp ${user}@${host}:/tmp ./file1 </dev/null
```

didn't help, same response, so it may need to have an stty command to zero tty input, I'm guessing now, per Kenster's note.

Comment: The fact that it prompts if key authentication fails means the server has password authentication enabled. Unless you can change the server config, you just have to deal with it. Now you also have the option of providing a client-side `~/.ssh/config` where you should be able to set `PasswordAuthentication no` and remove that as an authentication method (note: I haven't tried it, but I don't see why it wouldn't work). If it doesn't, the you are stuck with something like `echo "" | scp ${user}@$host}:/tmp ./file1 </dev/null` which would provide the empty-string on `stdin` in case of failure.

Comment: Also note, this is a question that may be interpreted as Off-Topic here since it isn't really "Programming" related, but more a "How do I use scp in case of key auth failure ...", so you may want to migrate the question to the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ssh (and scp and sftp) actually read passwords and passphrases from /dev/tty, not stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I create a blank input stream, that will not be prompting the user if the script is run interactively?

Instead of that disable password authentication.

```
scp -o BatchMode=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work as well

```
scp ${user}@${host}:/tmp ./file1 /dev/tty0 > /dev/null
```